# Collar for my kitten

Tags: collar

I have been trying for about two months for my kitten abjosting to wear her collar. We started of with collar without bell and I had try to give a treats or do it just before feeding. She literally had try to take it off and it stuck in her mouth, she was rolling on the carpet until I take it completely off. As soon as she sees the collar she hide and she wouldn't come out until she is sure that I don't have it in my hand. She wouldn't literally talk to me or come for r cuddles for good 2 - 3 hours. I don't know what to do any more I guess to  left its to give up with trying for her get use to the collar and  leave her be. Please help

Comment: Is there a compelling reason for you kitten to wear a collar?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make your cat wear a collar and still stay friends with her but it will take time.

Take it slow put the collar on your cat and let it stay on for a few minutes like 5 min  or so,slowly increase the time she wears it to 10 min and then 15 min and so on increase the time every day.

it might be better to give your cat the treats when you take the collar off her.

Be sure to use a collar that has a release,this needs to be adjusted to the weight of your cat so it dosent strangle her if she gets stuck.

Answer (score -1):

Collars can be dangerous for cats. A friend's cat managed to hang herself on one. If you must use a collar, use one that stretches (so that the cat can wriggle out of it), but better still, don't use one at all.

Comment: the op might have a good reason for using a collar on her cat,it is nice of you to inform the op of the dangers it poses for the cat,but you do not realy answer the question here.

Comment: @trondhansen The OP doesn't give any indication as to why the cat needs to wear a collar. The only possible answer to the implied question "How can I stop my cat from wriggling out of her collar", is to use one that is tight enough to prevent it happening, but this is extremely inadvisable. Perhaps you would like to suggest it? I am quite happy with my answer as it stands.

Comment: You could ask for the reason the op need a collar. And there are also collars with security-break-of. With this the collar is tight enough (also a secure thing: tight enough to not let twigs and similar too easy get stuck between) AND will break when the pressure is too high (when the cat gets stuck somewhere)